# Inverse Fourier Transformation of $1- \frac {s^2}{(1+s^2)^2}$

Tags: fourier-transform

How to find the Inverse Fourier Transformation of $\frac{1- s^2}{(1+s^2)^2}$ and $\frac{\sin(s)}{s}$?

I know I am supposed to use the table of inverse Fourier but I couldnt really find one that solves this.

Comment: The inverse transform of the second function (sinc) is the rectangle window function

Comment: Try: https://www.wolframalpha.com